# How does the particle な function in this sentence? ハングリー拗らせて吐きそうな人生

Tags: particles, song-lyrics, particle-な

> ハングリー拗らせて吐きそうな人生

I’m especially stuck on the “な人生” part. What is describing 人生? Is it the entire phrase before it, or just 吐きそう? From what I’ve gathered, the sentence must be something like “My hunger worsens, it feels like I’m going to vomit and that’s my life”, but I’ve seen it translated as “My hunger worsens, it feels like I’m going to vomit my life”.

Answer (score 1):

This そう is a Na-adjective, as [jisho.org's definition](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86) shows. That's why when it concludes a sentence it can be followed by だ. I say "can be" because the だ can also be omitted. And when it modifies a noun it should take な as the intervening particle.

ハングリー拗らせて吐きそう modifies 人生 and tells you what kind of 人生 it is. 吐きそう is the result of ハングリー拗らせて.

Comment: Thank you! So then, would my original assumption “My hunger worsens, it feels like I’m going to vomit and that’s my life” be roughly correct?

Comment: @Jehb Yep, sounds fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help! (: